# Angular 4 use the values from something.component.ts to the something.component.css

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am a bit new on Angular 4 so this might be a bit stupid question.. I got a value `photourl:string;` on my component.ts which contains the url of an image from my firebase database.. and I want to use this url as background-image for a div I got in my component.html so dispite {{photourl}} works fine in my component.html {{photourl}} in not recognised in my component.css.. Is there any way I can use typescript values in my component.css file directly or I need to use javascript from component.ts to intervene in the component.css?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ngStyle` directive.

```
<my-component [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': photoUrl }"></my-component>
```

Source: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Well I dont want to just have `'background-image': photoUrl` I want also to have these attributes:`height: 400px; 
 border: 1px solid #129CF3;
 background-color: black;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;` how I can do this with [ngStyle]??

Comment: Also `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': photoUrl }"` does not work :/ and can not find how to make it work..  `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(photoUrl)'  }"` ,  `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': url(photoUrl)  }" `neither work..